# How do I send information from ReactJS web application to ReactNative application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm creating a learning application for my school where teachers can make quizzes on a React web application but the information created will be seen on ReactNative application. What technologies do I have to keep in mind to make the teacher's input show up on a mobile application (connecting the two) and sending statistics back to the teacher? (images, text, averages)

Comment: What do you mean *keep is mind* ?

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings before i fully design the react native side are there stuff i need to know before attempting to connect the react and react native side. Im not an experienced programmer so i want to know what technologies i need or if its really simple to connect the two.

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings for example a Quizlet, how would they connect content created in web to be displayed in the mobile app

Comment: This would ideally require a backend programming language and a database and which one to pick would depend on what you are comfortable with. But SO is not the platform that can help you on this.

Comment: Webview? In react native to show your web page

Comment: @RaajNadar Thank you! That will get me a step closer to solving my problem.